# Running programs are not displayed in the panel

Tags: gnome, panel

My wifes computer is running ubuntu 10.04. Since several days the running programs are not displayed on the panel. With alt tab you can still switch between open programs. Any idea what happened?

Comment: In my case, all I did is "Right" click on panel, and choose Troubleshoot and then select "Restore all settings to default"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe the taskbar (Windows List) has been removed?

Right click on bottom panel, that click **Add to panel**, select **Windows List** and confirm.

Comment: I had to use **Alt** right click (Ubuntu 16.04 and gnome-flashback-metacity) to be able to open the context-menu

Comment: on Lubuntu 18.04 (its right click on taskbar -> manage widgets -> select add (+) -> Task Manager (Switch Between running application)

Answer (score 8):

Probably you have removed the Window List on the panel.

Right-click on the bottom panel and choose "Add To Panel" - select the "Window List" applet

[image]

Comment: In Xface edition this is called "Windows Button", if anybody is looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the window switcher got removed from the panel. Simply right click on it, and click add to panel. Then drag and drop the applet on to the panel, and it should be back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Adding more tips : Once you add the 'Windows List' into the task bar and only single folder appears on the bar, right click and remove that folder, soon you remove this new folder from the task bar all the open windows will get appeared on the task bar