# minimising windows problem

Tags: gnome

I'm new to Linux . I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and Gnome classic. I'm using the old Ubuntu desktop, not the new one that came with 11.04.

Can anybody tell me how to get minimised windows in the system tray?
Every time I minimise a window it just disappears and I have to use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> every time.

Comment: Maybe this answers can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Comment: Pal                                                           Thanx for help, but that is not my problem ,my problem is that I'm not seeing my minimised window,what i have to do to see them in task-bar. I'm fed up of using alt+tab and than selecting the required window form many windows which I minimised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what happened with so little info, but maybe you lost your windows list applet. Try this:

Move the mouse over one of the panels (either the bar on the top or bottom of the screen), press ALT and, at the same time, right click on the bar.

Select *Add to panel*, and in the new window select *Window List*.

Hope that it helps.

The source is this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63633/running-programs-are-not-displayed-in-the-panel), but updated to gnome-fallback (mainly you now need to use ALT to bring the menu).

Comment: pal                                                                let me say thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu man ,with such little info ur advise did it for me ,just one thing i want to add is that don't need to press alt key just simply go to the task bar and right click over it. it will show a menu in menu click add to panel click on it  and select window-list from it. it will do the work for u. once again thank u pal . I hope you could tell me hoe to install Hindi dictionary in linux

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer (click the green check) so that it counts as closed. Ask another question for the Hindi dictionary, I have no expertise in this, but this site is full with people with greater knowledge than mine.